# How to force ADf Validation in all fields even when they did not change

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to have a button that fires all validation in a ADF page. I need to evaluate all of them, even if the field has not changed its value.

Comment: Do you mean ADF Faces client side validation or ADF BC model validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Expose a method on the Application Module that calls validate() on the ViewObject Row. Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14022/oracle/jbo/server/ViewObjectImpl.html).
2. Call updateValuesFromRow on the [DCIteratorBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14022/oracle/adf/model/binding/DCIteratorBinding.html#updateValuesFromRow_oracle_jbo_Row_).  Though i have not tried this.
   At least it's a start.